# Drawing a matplotlib figure without drawing the lines

Tags: qt, matplotlib, pyside

I've embedded a matplotlib figure in a Qt (using PySide as bindings), and am using the draw function to redraw the figure:

```
self.canvas.figure.draw()
```

I'm also panning and zooming into this figure, and have been using the draw method to show the new perspectives from zooming in (using set_xlim and set_ylim) and from panning (drag_pan and start_pan). Is there a way to redraw the figure, but ignore redrawing any newly plotted points? When it pans, I'm making new plots using blit, but I want to make sure that this isn't being redone during the draw method and everything is running efficiently as possible

**Edit/Update:**
Below is a code snippet of how I'm panning (inspired by code from the navigationaltoolbar):

```
    def on_drag(self, event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y  

    if event.button == 1 and not event.dblclick and self.zoom.zoom_level != 0:

        self._button_pressed = 1
        self.cursor.dragging_enabled = True 

        self._xypress = [] 
        for i, a in enumerate(self.canvas.figure.get_axes()):

            if (x is not None and y is not None): # and a.in_axes(event)): 
                a.start_pan(x, y, event.button)
                self._xypress.append((a))
                self._idDrag = self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',
                                                   self.drag_pan)  

def drag_pan(self,event):

    self.canvas.update()
    self.canvas.flush_events()  

    x, y = self.calculate_center_coords()
    self.pan_center_x = x  
    self.pan_center_y = y  

    for a in self._xypress:

        a.drag_pan(self._button_pressed, event.key, event.x, event.y)
        x_diff = self.pan_center_x / event.xdata
        y_diff = self.pan_center_y / event.ydata

        if self.zoom.zoom_level == 1:
            if ((x_diff > 1.04590 and x_diff < 1.05090) or 
                              (x_diff < 0.95715 and x_diff > 0.95215) or 
                              (y_diff > 1.03550 and y_diff < 1.04450) or
                              (y_diff < 0.97215 and y_diff > 0.96115)): 

                x, y = self.calculate_center_coords()
                self.pan_center_x = x  
                self.pan_center_y = y  

                #Method that replots points using blit
                self.panning()

    #Redraws canvas, but is probably a bottleneck
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: why don't use the panning and zooming baked into the backend?

Comment: Do you mean using the panning and zooming included with the navigational toolbar? I've coded a variation of that, but I've created a map (using matplotlib), and I have clustered points. When I zoom in, new plots are created. When I pan, I need to be able to create new points, so I've modified the code from the navigationaltoolbar to get more control of the process. I've included some of the code above to show what I'm doing

Comment: I see.  It is clearer now.